# SQL Server Kafka connector in standalone mode not loading data in kafka

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using JDBC source Kafka connector to dump data from the SQL Server to Kafka in standalone mode. I have downloaded the **confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-5.5.0.zip** for the JDBC connector jars & copied all the jars at **plugin.path**. I am using the below worker & connector configuration.

- worker.peroperties

  ```
    value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
    plugin.path=/home/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/connector/plugin/
    offset.storage.file.filename=file
  ```
- connector1.properties

  ```
    name=test12_connector
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
    connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://host;databaseName=db;
    connection.user=user
    connection.password=password
    query=SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table;
    topic.prefix=test-
    mode=bulk
  ```

I am running connector in standalone mode using below command-

```
sh bin/connect-standalone.sh -daemon connector/worker.properties connector/connector1.properties
```

I am using the latest SQL Server JDBC driver & copied at the same plugin path.

Also, added same **plugin.path** in CLASSPATH.

But the issue I am facing that it is getting stuck at below lines in logs & not producing any data in the topic from the table (expected topic: test-table)

-logs

```
[2020-06-29 18:41:31,402] DEBUG Dialect SqlServerDatabaseDialect scored 100 against JDBC subprotocol 'sqlserver' and source 'jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=db;' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:127)
[2020-06-29 18:41:31,402] DEBUG Dialect SqliteDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'sqlserver' and source 'jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=db;' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:127)
[2020-06-29 18:41:31,402] DEBUG Dialect SybaseDatabaseDialect scored 100 against JDBC subprotocol 'sqlserver' and source 'jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=db;' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:127)
[2020-06-29 18:41:31,403] DEBUG Dialect VerticaDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'sqlserver' and source 'jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=db;' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:127)
[2020-06-29 18:41:31,403] DEBUG Using dialect SqlServerDatabaseDialect with score 100 against JDBC subprotocol 'sqlserver' and source 'jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=db;' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:133)
```

It is not even showing any error logs. I have changed the log level to TRACE but still, the connector is not showing any error & only shows the above logs.
Please help me out if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to play with connector properties probably adding:

```
"tasks.max": "1",
"internal.key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"reporter.admin.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
"internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
```

It also seems that it hangs not getting connection to source SQL server, so either connection string is not right or it can't find the driver JAR file for this dialect.
Check the logs if JDBC SQL Server dialect driver is loaded.

Comment: I have checked the logs JDBC SQL Server driver is loading
`DEBUG Registered java.sql.Driver: SQLServerDriver:7 to java.sql.DriverManager
Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/home/connector/plugin/mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8.jar}`

The weird thing is when I am using the wrong connection string then it's showing error "connect time out" & also on removing the plugin it's showing "No suitable driver found". Otherwise, it's getting hangs or not proceeding further.

Comment: Can it be that query takes ages to finish? As you write in comment - driver is surely loaded.

Comment: thanks for your response @adomas.m

It is resolved now. Some Firewall rule was blocking the connection on DB port. But I think Kafka connector should display some error for this firewall issue.